# Does DLL linking on windows results in GetProcAddress on runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm curious about how Dynamic Linking works on windows. Since we CAN NOT link to a directly, windows usually link your executable to a LIB file which contains the stub of functions exported by the DLL. Does this type of linking results in `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` at runtime? If not, how does the linking work internally?

Comment: You can have multiple versions of a DLL, which means that the functions it contains may be at different addresses, so yes, it would be necessary for the OS to call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. However, it's likely it uses internal versions of those functions rather than the publicly visible ones.

Comment: The address of the function is dynamic right? Since the address of the dll changes every time you load it. @CareyGregory

Comment: Indirectly, yes.  It is done by the operating system loader, it uses the import table in the executable file to know the DLL name and the name of the function that needs to be found.  Use Dumpbin.exe /imports to see what that table looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *maybe*.

The default method is to create an Import Table, which lists all required DLL's and the functions used from there. This table is parsed directly by the OS. It will probably reuse some of the same code behind LoadLibrary for that. It most likely will *not* use the code from `GetProcAddress` but prefer to do a single bulk lookup of all necessary functions.

*However* there's an MSVC feature called delay-loading. With this feature, MSVC++ will not build such an import table, but insert actual `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` calls. The benefit is that these calls are made at the latest possible moment. While you don't need a particular DLL, it's not loaded. This can accelerate program start up.